# Jmeter HTTP Request Sampler results in "connection refused"

Tags: jmeter

I am using windows8 and Jmeter the latest version. i created a simple HTTP Request Sampler and in the in the server name i added google.com

when i ran it i got the following error

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://google.com refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:286)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    ... 12 more
```

Is this because some permission issue or am I missing some parameter?

When I try to start jmeter with "run as administrator" I got the following error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Dumping heap to java_pid3344.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [48322830 bytes in 0.348 secs]
```

Answer (score 1):

the Kaspersky anti virus was blocking the Jmeter after disabling it i was able to use it